# Laravel whereHas

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following eloquent query that has two withs but wants the query more specific.

So far I have:

```
$club_models = \App\Models\Clubs\Club::whereActive(1)
            ->with('group_ex_pro_id')
            ->with('campaigns')->get();
```

I'd like it to be the below but am getting an error:

```
$club_models = \App\Models\Clubs\Club::whereActive(1)
            ->with('group_ex_pro_id')
            ->with('campaigns')->whereHas('new-campaign-name')->get();
```

I ultimately want it to include campaigns but want it to be where campaigns have the specific `new-campaign-name` name

Comment: And what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Where is your specific campaign name stored? In a variable? What is it called?

Comment: @Jacob, the error is 'Call to undefined method %s::%s()', static::class, $method

Comment: @Silidrone, no it is is not a variable. It is hard coded. So, in this case, it would be "new-campaign-name"

Comment: Yeah but then what is the name of the field that should be 'new-campaign-name'?

Comment: @Silidrone, in this case the real name is RunFit. 'new-campaign-name' was just dummy data

Comment: No I mean which field in the database should be equal to `new-campaign-name`, is it `campaigns.name`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need both `with` and `whereHas` together. Assuming the campaign name you'd like the campaigns to be is stored in `$campaignName`, try this:

```
$club_models = \App\Models\Clubs\Club::whereActive(1)
            ->with('group_ex_pro_id')
            ->whereHas('campaigns', function (Builder $query) use ($campaignName) {
                $query->where('new-campaign-name', $campaignName);
             })->get();
```

Comment: I get an error when I do that. It highlights this: $club_models = \App\Models\Clubs\Club::whereActive(1)